# I want to extract values from sender and reciver location?

Tags: python

```
a = {67: {'Sender_location': '1', 'Receiver_location': '6'},
     156: {'Sender_location': '2', 'Receiver_location': '4'}}


[g for i,g in a.items]
```

Comment: your keys are 101, 102 etc. Not sender_location

Comment: Its a dictionary under a dictionary! Thats why i have taken 2 loops .

Comment: why do have an else part, the current logic seems takes all the values

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: It is giving syntax error! If not putting else

Comment: the syntax for loop with if is different. I have posted the answer. Hopefully, that should help.

Comment: Values of sender and receiver location in a list ..like[ Area 1,Area 2.......n] ,[Area 4........n]

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the second `for` , there shouldn't be `else` part if you are just expecting values of "Sender_location" and "Receiver_location".

```py
>>>[[v for k,v in value.items() if k in ("Sender_location","Receiver_location")] for key,value in x.items()]
[['Area1', 'Area6'], ['Area2', 'Area4'], ['Area5', 'Area1'], ['Area1', 'Area4'], ['Area5', 'Area3'], ['Area3', 'Area1']]
```

To split the output into two lists (sender and receiver), you can use zip function:

```
>>> intial_output = [[v for k,v in value.items() if k in ("Sender_location","Receiver_location")] for key,value in x.items()]
>>> sender_list, receiver_list = map(list, zip(*intial_output))
>>> 
>>> sender_list 
['Area1', 'Area2', 'Area5', 'Area1', 'Area5', 'Area3']
>>> receiver_list
['Area6', 'Area4', 'Area1', 'Area4', 'Area3', 'Area1']
```

Comment: If we want a output like sender_locaton : [area1.area2....n] then what will be the syntax ?

Comment: you want to have a list of sendor_location and a list of receiver location ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Your `if/else` always return `v`, and that way should be use to get one value **or** another

```
v if k in ("Sender_location", "Receiver_location") else v
v if ... else v
```

#### Solution

What you need is a **filter** so the `if` may be after the `for` part

```
res = [[v for k, v in value.items() if k in ("Sender_location", "Receiver_location")]
       for value in dictionery3.values()]

# [['Area1', 'Area6'], ['Area2', 'Area4'], ['Area5', 'Area1'], 
   ['Area1', 'Area4'], ['Area5', 'Area3'], ['Area3', 'Area1']]
```

---

Group by key

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [(k, v) for value in dictionery3.values()
       for k, v in value.items() if k in ("Sender_location", "Receiver_location")]
res = {k: [x[1] for x in v] for k, v in groupby(sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])}


{'Receiver_location': ['Area6', 'Area4', 'Area1', 'Area4', 'Area3', 'Area1'], 
 'Sender_location': ['Area1', 'Area2', 'Area5', 'Area1', 'Area5', 'Area3']}
```

Comment: If we want a output like sender_locaton : [area1.area2....n]  then what will be the syntax